# How to find a video page in vimeo

Tags: video, internet, browser, vimeo

I've found a video embedded in a 3rd party site.

https://player.vimeo.com/video/168203444

I want to open this video in vimeo site to be able to add it to my personal "watch it later" list. How can I do that?

Comment: Someone who could understand that language should be able to skim keywords and search this faster than other methods like trying API calls because there seems to be no straight way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

The page at https://vimeo.com/player says, "Click the clock icon to save any Vimeo video to your Watch Later queue." Join Vimeo and log in to use this feature.